# Add day interval in DB2

Tags: db2

I am using DB2 version 12.1 and in a DB2 table AAA, I have a column 'Date' (Integer - column size 10) values as shown below,

[image]

Now my intention is to make a select query in the same table to display in Date format as shown below,

[image]

In Sql server, it works fine with the below query for example,

(DATEADD(day, AAA.DATE, '1849-12-31 01:01:01.1111111'))

But in DB2 , it not worked as expected, I tried with different functions DAYS,ADD_DAYS as shown below,

SELECT DAYS('1849-12-31') + 59169 AS TEST FROM AAA WHERE condition;

SELECT ADD_DAYS('1849-12-31', 59169) AS TEST FROM AAA WHERE condition;

How can I make it on DB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is differnt but simple and straight forward:

```
 select date('1849-12-31') + 58074 days from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Comment: It worked as expected Michael. If the date column is zero, Is it possible to return zero in the select query? Because now it returns '1849-12-31' if the date column is zero. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The zero problem should be adressed with a case statement